# Docker Memcached horizontal scaling

Tags: php, docker, memcached, horizontal-scaling

So I have a docker-compose setup and running for a site that I have been working on.  We are looking to deploy this to a docker cloud swarm for load balancing and deployment.

However, I have been looking into adding Memcached to this, but I can't seem to find a way to have my php services updated to reflect the increase in Memcached services.

E.g.  I scale Memcached up from 1 to 5, how can I update my application service to take advantage of all of these servers automatically?  I'm not afraid to switch to another system (redis, some other cache I can't remember atm) if they will let me do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the addServer method? http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.addserver.php
Then memcache will dispatch data and store it on one of the server.

Comment: Yes I’m aware of that, but if I scale a Docker stack from 5 memcached servers to 10, I have no way to add them to a production environment without shutting everything down.  Obviously any caching is still better than none but I was hoping for a way to automate the process.

Comment: Odds are I’ll have to implement a task in the laravel app, or cron to poll the Docker host for changes to memcached or whatever other service isn’t configurable to begin with.